# Does the Playstation 4 Support a 10TB hard drive?

Tags: ps4

Looking to upgrade my PS4 to 10TB. I've read that anything over 2TB, the stand by mode will not work. Is this still true? I wasn't sure if Sony updated the PS4 firmware to support >2TB?

Bottom line has anyone done a 4tb+ ps4 hard drive upgrade? And what are the pros/cons of it?

Comment: You should probably know that the PS4 only supports 2.5 inch drives. Are you definitely sure your 10 TB drive is small enough to fit?

Comment: @Nolonar considering I cannot find any information about any sort of 2.5" 10TB hard drive I would like to say it wouldn't fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the latest firmware update 4.50 the use of external hard drives is supported, though 8TB is the largest supported size.

Most models support an internal hard drive up to 4TB and unless you find a 2.5 inch one, you'll be stuck using a Data Bank (Nyko) like Timmy Jim described. The use of a data bank for 3.5 inch hard drives **used** to disable your stand-by mode.

If you wanted to test a 10TB hard drive (if you have one already) your safest bet would be to format it correctly and attach it like an external hard drive after you update to firmware 4.50.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your main question, I've found [an article](http://www.gamesradar.com/best-hard-drive-for-ps4/) that says certain models can support up to an 8TB hard drive.

> PlayStation 4s with a model number below CUH-1200 can accommodate drives up to 4TB in capacity, while PS4s with a model number above CUH-1200 can handle up to 8TB.

However, you'd be hard pressed to find an 8TB hard drive that is 2.5 inches.  You can use something called a [Nyko Data Bank](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00UA55ZRI) which will allow you to use 3.5 inch drives, but it's essentially an external hard drive closure, and will add to the size of your PS4 (not a big deal, unless your PS4 is in a small space).

From the page I found, I don't think a 10TB drive will be supported.  Realistically, 8TB should be more than enough (it would be for me!).  The article also noted that a 6TB hard drive would be more preferred from a cost perspective, but if cost isn't a factor then there are certainly some 8TB options available.

Comment: how about the stand by issue?

Comment: @duckx it looks like from [this article](http://nyko.com/blogs/news/81188612-2tb-restriction-lifted-from-nyko-data-bank-for-newer-ps4-models) which talks about that Nyko Data Bank, the rest mode is unaffected.  Your firmware needs to be 3.50 or up it seems.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that 3.5 inch 10TB HDD (I tried Seagate) & 12TB HDD both work in external and internal modes without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely better off using an external hard drive for your PS4, especially since update 4.50 added the support.

Although 10TB is a bit excessive for my needs there are external hard drives for PS4 that [go up to 8TB on this list](http://thegizmolife.com/best-ps4-external-hard-drive/).

I'm pretty sure there aren't 10TB internal hard drives you can use on the PS4. I've looked but that was months ago. The PS4 only takes a certain hard drive size and the higher storage capacity internal hard drives start at 3.5 inches which aren't compatible with the PS4.

Comment: B.M. Garrett,
How did you get the Playstation to recognize and use the external harddrive of a 10tb size? Mine won't accept that size.

Comment: @starchild83 They didn't.  It sounds like 8TB is the highest you can use.